# Why HLS sampler error is showing blank error

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I was trying to add a HLS Sampler for a  VOD content with low bandwidth and min resolution but in results I am getting a blank error.

[image]

Comment: Could you try to add any more detail ? About what you have tried before you first saw this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to `Raw` mode in order to be able to see request details as HLS Sampler cannot be cast to HTTP Request sampler therefore `HTTP` mode is not available even in the case when the sampler is successful:

[image: JMeter HLS Sampler Success]

And in Raw mode you should see the URL for your HLS playlist:

[image: JMeter HLS URL]

Check out [The New HLS Plugin for JMeter - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-hls-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide) article for comprehensive information on setting up and using the HTLS Plugin.